# calling the value determined by the askopenfilename command using python Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, python-2.5

Hi I've made a simple GUI that contains a browse button which uses `askopenfilename` :

```
browsebutton = Button(mGui,text='Browse',command=askopenfilename)
browsebutton.place(x=400,y=50)
```

I have been trying to print this file name to a text file as part of a larger script, I have tried many different strategies, my last attempt was this:

```
conf.write("receptor="'invoke(browsebutton)'"\n")
```

I'm having touble finding out how to call this function, I just started programming and I have tried multiple strategies but none seem to work. I am using Python 2.5, thank you for your help. -Paul

Comment: I tried indenting 4 spaces for the code but for some reason its not working

Comment: use:
`from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename` & then use your code

Answer (score 0):

Create function with `askopenfilename()` and assign it to button

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename 

def some_function():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    if filename:
        print "selected:", filename
    else:
        print "file not selected"

mGui = tk.Tk()
browsebutton = tk.Button(mGui,text='Browse',command=some_function)
browsebutton.pack()

mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get to this but i cant seem to get it to work, i tried multiple iterations of this and this is the simplest form and it says receptor file not defined
...
    import sys
    from Tkinter import * #for GUI
    from tkFileDialog import * #for browse button function

    mGui = Tk()

    mGui.geometry('500x400+300+100')
...
    def receptorfilename():
        receptorfile = askopenfilename()
        return

    def generate():
        conf = open('invoke(browsebutton3)'+e10.get()+".txt","w")
        conf.write("receptor="+receptorfile.get()+"\n")
        conf.close()

Comment: continued
    `browsebutton = Button(mGui,text='Browse',command=receptorfilename)`
    `browsebutton.place(x=400,y=50)`
...
    `mGui.mainloop()`